# soma de valores de mais de uma tabela

Tags: sql

Estou com um problema no código abaixo. Quando coloco para somar o campo `valor` da tabela `lnota`, ele traz um resultado errado da conta; se deixo somente o campo, ele traz o valor certo

```
SELECT projeto.Projeto, 
   COALESCE(SUM(recebimento.Valor), 0) AS Total, 
   COALESCE(SUM(contaspagar.Valor), 0) AS Total2, 
   COALESCE(SUM(lnota.Valor), 0) AS Tota3 
FROM projeto 
LEFT JOIN recebimento ON recebimento.Projeto = projeto.IdProjeto 
LEFT JOIN contaspagar ON contaspagar.Projeto = projeto.IdProjeto 
LEFT JOIN lnota ON lnota.Projeto = projeto.IdProjeto 
GROUP BY projeto.Projeto
```

Comment: Precisamos da estrutura das tabelas, dados contidos e resultado esperado com esses dados.

Answer (score 0):

## O Problema

O problema está na forma em que o `left join` está sendo empregado, visto que a relação 1 para muitos entre as várias relações unidas acarretam a repetição de valores conforme correspondências das chaves da consulta.
Como para 1 projeto pode haver N recebimentos, teremos no final do `left join` todas as tuplas da tabela projeto mais todas as tuplas de recebimento

## Exemplos de soluções

1. Utilizando uma subconsulta para cada tabela gerando uma **coluna** de total

   ```
   SELECT projeto.idprojeto, projeto.projeto, 
   (select COALESCE(SUM(recebimento.valor), 0)  
      from recebimento 
      where recebimento.projeto = projeto.idprojeto) AS Total_Recebimento,
   (select COALESCE(SUM(contaspagar.valor), 0)  
      from contaspagar 
      where contaspagar.projeto = projeto.idprojeto) AS Total_contaspagar,
   (select COALESCE(SUM(lnota.Valor), 0)  
      from lnota 
      where lnota.projeto = projeto.idprojeto) AS Total_lnota
   FROM projeto
   ```
2. Utilizando uma subconsulta para gerar relações sumarizadas por projeto e juntá-las através do `left join`

   ```
   SELECT p.*, 
          COALESCE(r.Total_Recebimento, 0) as Total_Recebimento, 
          COALESCE(cp.Total_contaspagar, 0) as Total_contaspagar,
          COALESCE(n.Total_lnota, 0) as Total_lnota
   FROM projeto p
   LEFT JOIN (select recebimento.projeto, SUM(recebimento.valor) AS Total_Recebimento 
                from recebimento 
                group by projeto) r on r.projeto = p.idprojeto 
   LEFT JOIN (select contaspagar.projeto, SUM(contaspagar.valor) AS Total_contaspagar 
                from contaspagar 
                group by projeto) cp on cp.projeto = p.idprojeto 
   LEFT JOIN (select lnota.projeto, SUM(lnota.Valor)  AS Total_lnota 
                from lnota 
                group by projeto) n on n.projeto = p.idprojeto
   ```

## "Descobrindo" o problema

Para você descobrir a causa do problema, sugiro que execute um `select` sem as somas e sem o `group by` para saber quais valores o SGBD está somando, ou seja, verificar os dados em detalhes.

```
    SELECT *
      FROM projeto 
      LEFT JOIN recebimento ON projeto.idprojeto = recebimento.projeto 
      LEFT JOIN contaspagar ON projeto.idprojeto = contaspagar.projeto
      LEFT JOIN lnota ON projeto.idprojeto  = lnota.projeto 
     WHERE projeto.idprojeto = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Talvez essa alteração já resolva seu problema.

Acredito que o SUM esteja retornando NULL, e o coalesce faz ele pegar o próximo valor que é 0.

Da forma como fiz o NULL já é validado antes da função SUM, retornando o resultado que você quer.

```
    SELECT projeto.Projeto, 
           SUM(isnull(recebimento.Valor, 0)) AS Total, 
           SUM(isnull(contaspagar.Valor, 0)) AS Total2, 
           SUM(isnull(lnota.Valor, 0)) AS Tota3 
    FROM projeto 
    LEFT JOIN recebimento ON recebimento.Projeto = projeto.IdProjeto 
    LEFT JOIN contaspagar ON contaspagar.Projeto = projeto.IdProjeto 
    LEFT JOIN lnota ON lnota.Projeto = projeto.IdProjeto 
    GROUP BY projeto.Projeto
```